# How to operate Packages and Inno Setup by script?

Tags: shell-script, automation, applescript

I am new in scripting. And I would like to automate my deploying process. And now I am trying to write script which will compile and build installator file by [OSX Packages](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html) (and for Windows [Inno Setup](https://jrsoftware.org/isdl.php)).

At the moment I do that by open application and then call keyboard shortcut. Like that:

```
tell application "Packages"
    activate
    open "pathToMyPackageProject.pkgproj"
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "b" using command down
    end tell
end tell
```

And this does what I want. But I feel like calling System Events keyboard shortcuts is not good solution in that case. I can imagine that my shortcut will be captured by some other application or on other document.

So isn't there any script command that allows me to tell Packages (and Inno Setup) to run exact operation on exact project file? Something like:

```
tell application "Packages"
    compile and build "pathToMyPackageProject.pkgproj"
end tell
```

I suppose I need something called API for those applications. But I can't find it by google.
So I wonder is there any elegant way to call operations in any application which I don't know the API?

As far as I know I can also list operations from application menu bar and then choose item which I need. But to be honest I am not sure how to perform it. I don't understand the syntax how to do that. And also I am afraid what if application menu bar will be changed after some update. So not sure what to do?

For any advice great thanks in advance.
Best Regards

Comment: The way to determine applescript support for an application is to open 'Script Editor', and in that File > Open Dictionary…. This results in a list of apps being displayed. If you find Packages in the list, choose it. A document will open that shows what commands are available. FWIW, while it's possible that the app has applescript functionality, it also may have shell functionality (which incidentally would be accessible to applescript).

Comment: Great thanks for your reply. For sure I will check your suggestion. But what if in Dictionary there can't be find my application (in that case Packages) or exact command which I need? And what about the windows? Is there anything like AppleScript Dictionary for Windows?

Comment: If the application is not listed, then that application does not support applescript. Basically, whatever support the developer adds will show up in the dictionary. So even if there is a dictionary, it is very possible that not every feature will be supported. What you've done — UI scripting — should work with any app though. As to Windows? There is no applescript support for any windows app (as it requires things in the OS which of course, aren't in windows). But given the purpose of the app (both of them), it may very have its own scripting mechanism.